# How to prevent an mdadm array check from consuming excessive system resources?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

Once a month I've been doing

```
echo check > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action
```

in order to force a software raid consistency check.  The problem is this is a 7.2T RAID 5.  The consistency check takes days to complete and while it's running, everything on my system slows to a crawl.  Is there any way to nice this (say by temporarily setting `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max` to something smaller for the duration of the check?

In general it pains me that even in the 4.13 linux kernel, extended disk I/O causes the system to grind to a halt; should be a solved problem by now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing Linux Software RAID Rebuild Speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/625722/reducing-linux-software-raid-rebuild-speed)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I read the question you link to before posting.  The question you're referring to concerns RAID rebuild times.  I'm asking about consistency checks for an (apparently) healthy RAID.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to throttle the check process? You recognize that if this is possible the process will take longer, and even with throttling, there will still be a slowdown.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a way to nice the check process (with full understanding that this will make it take longer).  I've never understood why certain kinds of sustained I/O slow the system down so much.  Maybe that has something to do with the hardware architecture?  How interrupts work, or something like this?

Comment: I have similar issues.  Linux softraid should intelligently reduce sanity check speed as system load increases, but this seems not to happen.  My server can get load factors in the 40-60 range as tasks get backed up - the backlog clears up in a minute or two  but can then reappear a few minutes later, depending on system demands.  Manually overriding /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max solves the problem, of course, but at the expense of the sanity check being much slower if the setting is left there.